# Find a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ whose image is spanned by $(1,2,3)$ and $(4,5,6)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

Here's the problem:

> Find a linear map $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that the image is spanned by $(1,2,3)$ and $(4,5,6)$.

Here's my work:

If we think of a matrix for $T$, say $[T]$, then we want the column space to be spanned by $(1,2,3)$ and $(4,5,6)$, since $\mathrm{Im}(T) =$ columnspace$([T])$. So any matrix with columns in $\{(1,2,3), (4,5,6)\}$ should work, e.g.

$[T] = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 & 1\\
2 & 5 & 2 \\
3 & 6 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$.

Correct? Thanks!

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: You don't need to have those literal columns. Any linear combinations will do, provided you have a $2$-dimensional span.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @TedShifrin So any column in the span of $(1,2,3)$ and $(4,5,6)$ should also work? Is that what you are saying? Thanks!

Comment: I'm saying that as long as you don't choose just multiples of *one* vector, any linear combinations will do.

Comment: Thanks! Got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You can completely categorize a linear transformation by its action on a basis set of the domain space.  And since $T(1,0,0)=T(0,0,1)=(1,2,3)$ and $T(0,1,0)=(4,5,6)$ by your matrix definition, the range of $T$ will be the span of the two vectors.